# Perl script to extract part of some numbers

Tags: perl

I wrote a Perl script that reads from a file and do so calculations. Basically I 'm trying to calculate the Throughput of network traffic. The file I'm reading from has the following format:

```
- 0.152416 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 12.0 2.9 2 13
r 0.153584 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 12.0 2.9 1 12
+ 0.154208 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 10.0 2.7 3 15
- 0.154208 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 11.0 2.8 3 15
r 0.155248 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 12.0 2.9 2 13
```

I'm extracting column[0] , [3], [7], [8], [9]. Since column [8] and [9] comes as double (i.e. x.y), I was trying to get only the first part of column[8] and [9] (i.e x part). In other words, I don't care about the second part that comes after the dot "." . All I need the first part. I guess, I have two ways, whether to deal with regular expressions or add more extra code to customize the token in [8] and [9] for each line I will read?. Any short suggestion. part of the script:

```
#input parameters:
$infile=$ARGV[0];
$dest=$ARGV[1];
$from=$ARGV[2];
$to=$ARGV[3];
$fId=$ARGV[4];
$TimeShift=$ARGV[5];
```

I want to make $from and $to contains only the first part.

```
open (DATA,"<$infile") || die "error in  $infile $!";
while (<DATA>) 
   {  
  @x = split(' ');  Im using space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$from = int $ARGV[2];
```

See [int](http://p3rl.org/int) for details.

Or, rather,

```
my ($infile, $dest, $from, $to, $fId, $TimeShift) = @ARGV;
$_ = int for $from, $to;
```

Comment: Thank you . But this giving me Zero results for all the nodes while if I specify the second part (not using integer), the throughput is calculated.?

Comment: @Eng.Mohd: Without seeing the script, I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware though, that while you can use `int`, that it has some dangerous caveats.

From `perldoc -f int`:

> You should not use this function for rounding: one because
>                  it truncates towards 0, and two because machine representations
>                  of floating-point numbers can sometimes produce
>                  counterintuitive results.  For example, "int(-6.725/0.025)"
>                  produces -268 rather than the correct -269; that's because it's
>                  really more like -268.99999999999994315658 instead.  Usually,
>                  the "sprintf", "printf", or the "POSIX::floor" and
>                  "POSIX::ceil" functions will serve you better than will int().

Instead, consider doing:

```
using POSIX;
...
...

$from = POSIX::floor($ARGV[2]);
```

Comment: It appears, though, that the OP's not rounding, as the specs say, "...I don't care about the second part that comes after the dot '.' ." and the OP's data set will not cause `int` to "produce counterintuitive results".  Given this, `int`'s a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to throw away the dots and following digits, you can use `s/[.][0-9]+\z//`. That way, no floating point conversions would be involved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my @cols = (split ' ', $line)[0, 3, 7 .. 9];
    s/[.][0-9]+\z// for @cols[-2 .. -1];
    print Dumper \@cols;
}

__DATA__
- 0.152416 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 12.0 2.9 2 13
r 0.153584 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 12.0 2.9 1 12
+ 0.154208 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 10.0 2.7 3 15
- 0.154208 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 11.0 2.8 3 15
r 0.155248 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 2 12.0 2.9 2 13
```